# Counting certain items in a list then using that output in an if statement

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, if-statement

I'm trying to develop a program that takes an number of inputs from a user then counts the particular number of times that number has been entered by the user then using that information decide what is the most common.

```
from collections import Counter
results = []
while len(results)<7:
    entered=int(raw_input('enter results:'))
    results.append(entered)

print results

distribution = Counter(results)

print distribution
```

it will output something like this:

```
enter results:1
enter results:2
enter results:3
enter results:2
enter results:6
enter results:5
enter results:4
[1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4]
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

from here i want to be able to take the information given at the end and tell the user which i the most common, i know the user can see it from the counter output, but its part of a task i have been given. i was thinking about using some along the lines of

```
if 2 >= 4:
     print 'most common.'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `distribution.most_common(1)` for instance?

Comment: By `2 >= 4` do you mean an item is "most common" only if it appears at least 4 times?

Comment: @ettanany yeah, i just used that as an example because i have only had 6 inputs so that could change.

Comment: Jon, i've just tried 'distribution.most_common(1)' it works, but not quite what i was after, that just displays what the most common one is, i would like to given the user feedback depending on what that most common one is.

Comment: `most_common = distribution.most_common(1)` will give you `[(2, 2)]` and you can do `print('most common is {}'.format(most_common[0][0]))`! not what you want?

Comment: Oh no sorry, i've got it wrong, it needs to print out something based on a criteria, e.g if 4 came up 4 times.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want exactly.

Comment: @user3092467 can you [edit] your question to give examples of what you actually want to display to the user and the criteria for that? It's a little fuzzy what you really want here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the output of distribution.most_common, but if that doesn't work, here's a fairly simple loop that does the job

```
most_common = 0
for i in distribution:
    if distribution[i] > distribution[most_common]:
        most_common = i

print most_common
```

Also, if you would need to know if the frequency of that number is more than half of the input, you could have

```
if distribution[most_common] > 7./2:
    more_than_half = True
else:
    more_than_half = False
```

Comment: Also, since it isn't exactly clear (to me at least), I'll point out that in the loop, `i` is the list of different numbers you input, and `distribution[i]` is how often `i` occurs.

Comment: I basically what what you've done with one extra step, so once we've found the most common then put it into an if statement and see if it appears over a certain amount of times, in this case 4 e.g. 'if most_common > 4: print this is biased'

Comment: As I put in the second code block, you'd want `if distribution[most_common]` instead of just `most_common` . Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: I've just added that in and its come up with this error                     
 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task 2.py", line 21, in <module>
    if distribution(most_common) > 4:
TypeError: 'Counter' object is not callable'

Comment: It was meant to have square braces. Its `distribution[most_common]`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you want is the following:

```
from collections import Counter

distribution = Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})

most_common_item = distribution.most_common(1)
print('most common is: {}'.format(most_common_item[0][0]))  # Output: most common is: 2
```